# VS Code doesn't print output properly

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

I observed some kind of Heisenbug, I think: in VS Code, I run the following program:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    print("Start...")
    print("...end.")
    // println()
    // System.out.close()
  }
}
```

If I run the program several times, say ten times, in the *debug console* tab about two times I get what I'd expect, but eight times I get no output at all.

If I uncomment either of the last two lines I get the correct output everytime.

And if I replace `print("...end.")` by `print("...end.\nBye.")`, the output text `Start......end.` is printed everytime, but the output `Bye.` is only shown sporadically.

Do you know why that happens?

With IntelliJ IDEA I do not observe this behavior: there, I get the "correct" output everytime.

Comment: Not flushing your output is a programming bug.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it is cleaner to always flush / close the output stream before exiting the program. But I'd like to understand why it's not printed in VS Code. If you call the program in the terminal, the ouput prints "as it should", and in IntelliJ IDEA too. Also, doing `System.out.flush()` seems to be not sufficient in VS Code: I still only occasionally get the last line of output.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html seems to be relevant. I didn't know that I have to flush the output stream.

Comment: I believe that when a program finish it flushes it's outputs, but you should not depend on that. What is not explicit in your code is subject to implementation details that may change, like in this case.